# Linear Algebra- Spanning

Tags: linear-algebra

For every vector x in R^3 there is a choice of a,b and c for which x is contained in the span of (0,a,b),(-a,0,c),(-b,-c,0).True or false?

How to prove this statement if I think it is true?anyone can guide? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make your vectors the rows of a matrix and see if it is invertible by computing the reduced row echelon form. If at least one row is always 0 regardless of choices, then it isn't true. If none of the rows are always 0, then the question reduces to which choices of variable values are allowed. Since at this point there will be 1s on the diagonal, the only thing that can go wrong is division by 0. This would have happened in some intermediate step.

Comment: I remembered I saw for showing spanning is put each vector into the column and form a matrix? what is the difference between your comment n my understanding?

Comment: Columns or rows will both work. The key is to show that the matrix is invertible.